# Keeping footer below content

Tags: html, css, footer

I have two divs next to each other positioned using absolute. but when i try to make a footer it apears behind the two divs. how can i have it be below them? it needs to be dynamic so if i make one of the divs bigger the footer will stay below.

here is a quick fiddle i made to show it.
https://jsfiddle.net/po7159rf/
or

```
`<div class="left">
    <p>left div</p>
</div>`

`<div class="right">
    <p>right div</p>
</div>`

`<footer>Footer</footer>`

`.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}`

`.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}`

`footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}`
```

Comment: Google *sticky footer HTML 5* and take your pick of techniques; all of them push the footer to at least the longer of the two columns. Most additionally put the footer at the bottom of the viewport if the content is vertically short.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by adding a **parent div** to left and right div's. Set min-height and relative positioning property to the parent div.
Please find the modified code below.

```
<style>
.parent {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 70px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="left">
    <p>
        left div
    </p>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <p>
        Right div
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<footer>
Footer
</footer>
```